# Multipass umount not finding Home

Tags: ubuntu

I want to set up an isolated Ubuntu virtual machine on my MacBook Pro.

Once it is deployed, I will run:

```
multipass umount pi:/home/ubuntu/Home
```

and I get

```
umount failed: The following errors occurred:
path "/home/ubuntu/Home" is not mounted in 'pi'
```

and

```
$ multipass list
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
pi                      Running           192.168.64.90    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

How can I prevent Multipass from mounting the host under `/home/ubuntu/Home`?

Comment: Please run `multipass info pi | grep Mounts` and **edit your question** to add the results to it.

Comment: due to another problem with 1.12 static IPs I've abandonned multipass - at least for now. apologies, best to let the thread know.